# React shallow rendering generates component with type == Function instead of type == <ComponentName>

Tags: reactjs, jasmine

Assuming the following 2 components

```js
var Level2 = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return      React.createElement('div');
  }

});

var Level1 = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return      React.createElement(Level2);
    }
});
```

and the following helper for shallow rendering testing in Jasmine

```js
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

var shallowRender = function(element, props, children) {
    var ShallowRenderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();
    ShallowRenderer.render(React.createElement(element, props, children));
    return ShallowRenderer.getRenderOutput();
};
```

The second test does not behave as I expect:

```js
describe ('test rendered output', function (){
    it('level 2 should render a div component', function() {
       l2 = shallowRender(Level2);
        expect(l2.type).toBe('div')   // this test PASSES
    });

    it('level 1 should render a level 2 component', function() {
        l1 = shallowRender(Level1);
        // this test FAILS with the following message  'Expected Function to be 'Level2'
        expect(l1.type).toBe('Level2')  
    })
});
```

Any idea why the second test fails ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type a JSX tag name with a lowercase letter

```js
<div />
```

the JSX is transpiled into

```js
React.createClass("div")
```

and thus the element type is a string — `"div"`. But when you use an uppercase letter

```js
<Level2 />
```

the JSX turns into

```js
React.createClass(Level2)
```

and the type of the component is *not* a string (e.g. `"Level2"`), but is in fact the actual value `Level2`. Your test should read

```js
expect(l1.type).toBe(Level2)
```

Comment: so simple and so obvious. thanks for opening my eyes :)